# How can I use Rails Validations to allow and attribute variable to be one of two values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activemodel

For a project, I need the categories attribute of the Post class to be either "Fiction" or "Non-Fiction." I attempted the following syntax...

```
class CategoryValidator < ActiveModel::Validator 
    def validate(record)
        unless (record.category == "Fiction" || "Non-Fiction")
            record.errors[:category] << "Must be valid category" 
            binding.pry
        end
    end
end
```

but it never hit the binding.pry line, meaning it never hit "until" block, even when I entered purposefully wrong answers. What would the proper syntax for the #validate method be?

Comment: Can you share the `Post` model code?

Comment: `class Post < ActiveRecord::Base include ActiveModel::Validations
    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :content, length: {minimum: 100}
    validates_with CategoryValidator
end`

Answer (score 1):

Your condition to check if the category is either `'Fiction'` or `'Non-Fiction'` isn't right.

`(record.category == "Fiction" || "Non-Fiction")` is evaluated as `(record.category == "Fiction") || "Non-Fiction"` since `==` has higher precedence than `||`. As a result, the expression will always return `"Non-Fiction"` which is truthy. That's why your code never got to the `binding.pry` line even when the category wasn't "valid".

```rb
def validate(record)
  unless %w(Fiction Non-Fiction).include?(record.category)
    record.errors[:category] << "Must be valid category"
  end
end
```

A custom validator is an overkill for this use-case. You can use [`inclusion`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion) to add this validation.

```rb
validates :category, inclusion: {
  in: %w(Fiction Non-Fiction),
  message: 'must be either Fiction or Non-Fiction'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate myself, such a simple fix and I got it

```
class CategoryValidator < ActiveModel::Validator 
    def validate(record)
        unless (record.category == "Fiction" || record.category == "Non-Fiction")
            record.errors[:category] << "Must be valid category" 
        end
    end
end
```